# How to import data from Azure SQL Azure Database to Excel Online

Tags: excel, azure-sql-database, powerquery, excel-online

If I want to import data from Azure SQL Database to an Excel file I can easily go into

Data > Get Data > From Azure > From Azure SQL Database

and Power Query will take care of the `REST` (couldn't avoid the pun, sorry):

[image]

But then I want to do this with Excel online so the file could refresh daily and be available for my colleagues.

Luckily Microsoft provides a guide called: [How to refresh data to a SQL Azure Database in Excel Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/excel-online-refreshing-data-to-a-sql-azure-database) and guess what? I'm stuck in the very first step.

In fact the guide tells to go into

Data > From Other Sources > From Data Connection Wizard

But there is no such thing in Excel Online:

[image]

How to connect Excel Online to Azure SQL Database and pull data?

Comment: From the page you linked to step 13 says "Upload this workbook to Excel Online".  That to me indicates you need to create it in your local install of excel.

Comment: I reported the documentation (the URL you shared with us) as outdated. Thisseems to be no possible anymore on Excel online.

Comment: Thank you @AlbertoMorillo, where can I report that?

Comment: I reported the issue here. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/microsoft-365-docs/issues/12908

Comment: Usually Microsoft Docs have the "This page" button at the bottom of each page for you to report this type of issues. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/quickstart-content-reference-guide?view=azuresql. But the page you shared with us does not have it.

Comment: I can see the button. I will report. Thank you

Comment: Here is the GitHub link: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/115684 .
@AlbertoMorillo, you can post your answer if you want and I will upvote that. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As @Alberto Morillo said the document is an outdated and the options showed in document is not visible or supported in Excel online.**

**The doc you provided in that in last point they said you need to upload it in excel online by storing it in OneDrive.**

To achieve your scenario, you need to first create excel and connect it to SQL database. and get the table the upload the excel to OneDrive.

[image]

and if you refresh the excel from local it will show changes in the excel online if you open it.
[image]

Update:

You can enable auto refresh option for connection so it will get automatically refreshed as below.

**Quires & Connections >> Connection Properties >> Last refreshed**

[image]

Comment: Does it means that if I update the table in Azure SQL Database the change will be reflected into the Excel file? 
I don't think so because I cannot managed the refresh if it's hourly or daily

Comment: check the updated section.

Comment: Thank you @Pratick . I set the refresh to 1440 minutes. Does it means that if I go to holiday for 2 weeks nothing will refresh as I don't turn on my PC? 
Because I want this to be flowless. Maybe Power Automate or Logic App is a better approach?